# Error loading already trained ner spacy model

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to load an already trained NER model, which was loading normally until today, but I'm getting the following error, either importing the trained model or importing pt_core_news_lg:

`nlp4 = spacy.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/spacy_NER4')`

**ValueError: Cannot create vectors table with dimension 0. If you're using pre-trained vectors, are the vectors loaded?**

I'm on Google Colab, following the installations:

`!pip install spacy==2.3.4`

`!python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg`

When I import my model, it generates this error. Does anyone have a tip or solution to this problem?

If I install spacy-nightly it throws another error:

**OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from /content/gdrive/My Drive/space_NER4/config.cfg**

However, when loading pt_core_news_lg, it loads normally

Comment: spacy-nightly hasn't been updated in over a year, since spaCy v3 was released. Are you sure you're still using spaCy v2? Maybe colab upgraded their Python version and there are no longer wheels for the old spaCy...? The output of `spacy info` could be helpful here.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by switching accounts. I made backups of all the trained models and loaded them again, in the same way, in colab from another account of mine (I simply imported all the colab and files and it ran). So far it's working. The issue with not having the config.cfg, is because I'm actually loading the most updated version of spacy, while the training data and folders of the previous version are different. So, in the newest spacy, it's not finding the .cfg file.
Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by changing google account. I simply imported all my templates into the other account and it worked. However, the reason for the error of not loading in the account, I did not find

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).